# how retreive firebase data based on unique key value in Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am getting all `"items"` entries from firebase database here.
What actually need it to give me only the entries from specific `unique key`

```
ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Sales")
ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
    override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
    }
    override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            }
            override fun onDataChange(p1: DataSnapshot) {
                println("onDataChange")
                if (p0.exists()) {
                    list.clear()
                    for (h in p0.children) {
                        if (h.hasChild("items")) {
                            val generic: GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<Product>> =  object : GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<Product>>() {}
                            val items = h.child("items").getValue(generic)
                            items?.let { productList.addAll(it) }
                        }
                        val adapter = ReceiptItemsAdapter(applicationContext, productList)
                        rReceyclerView.adapter = adapter
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
})
```

I have tried like this but it didn't work, didn't give any error too.

```
 ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Sales/-Lw37uyfuBA0AfTalp")
```

here is my json file

```
{
  "-Lw37uyfuBA0AfTalp": {
    "date": "14\/12\/2019",
    "discount": 0.24,
    "due": 0,
    "items": [
      {
        "pamount": 2.4,
        "pname": "Granola",
        "pprice": 2.4,
        "punit": 1
      }
    ],
    "paym": [
      {
        "paymentAmnt": 0.02,
        "paymentDesc": "Cash Payment :"
      },
      {
        "paymentAmnt": 2.14,
        "paymentDesc": "Card Payment :"
      }
    ],
    "subTotal": 2.4,
    "time": "11:16:42",
    "total": 2.16
  },
  "-Lw5Qx8sVdw3ZCMiXAL-": {
    "date": "14\/12\/2019",
    "discount": 1,
    "due": 0,
    "items": [
      {
        "pamount": 4.8,
        "pname": "Granola",
        "pprice": 2.4,
        "punit": 2
      },
      {
        "pamount": 2.6,
        "pname": "Brownie",
        "pprice": 2.6,
        "punit": 1
      },
      {
        "pamount": 2.6,
        "pname": "Brownie",
        "pprice": 2.6,
        "punit": 1
      }
    ],
    "name": "James Brown",
    "paym": [
      {
        "paymentAmnt": 3,
        "paymentDesc": "Cash Payment :"
      },
      {
        "paymentAmnt": 5,
        "paymentDesc": "Staff Markout :"
      },
      {
        "paymentAmnt": 1,
        "paymentDesc": "Card Payment :"
      }
    ],
    "subTotal": 10,
    "time": "22:03:07",
    "total": 9
  },
  "-Lw5T4TfYUTXsWKAndBx": {
    "date": "14\/12\/2019",
    "discount": 0.24,
    "due": -0.84,
    "items": [
      {
        "pamount": 2.4,
        "pname": "Granola",
        "pprice": 2.4,
        "punit": 1
      }
    ],
    "name": "James Brown",
    "paym": [
      {
        "paymentAmnt": 3,
        "paymentDesc": "Cash Payment :"
      }
    ],
    "subTotal": 2.4,
    "time": "22:12:26",
    "total": 2.16
  },
  "-Lw5UWguHS18IwWE6elT": {
    "date": "14\/12\/2019",
    "discount": 0.26,
    "due": -1.66,
    "items": [
      {
        "pamount": 2.6,
        "pname": "Brownie",
        "pprice": 2.6,
        "punit": 1
      }
    ],
    "name": "James Brown",
    "paym": [
      {
        "paymentAmnt": 4,
        "paymentDesc": "Cash Payment :"
      }
    ],
    "subTotal": 2.6,
    "time": "22:18:43",
    "total": 2.34
  },
  "-Lw5ypp5xJLJO53bjejk": {
    "date": "15\/12\/2019",
    "discount": 0,
    "due": -1.6,
    "items": [
      {
        "pamount": 2.4,
        "pname": "Granola",
        "pprice": 2.4,
        "punit": 1
      }
    ],
    "name": "James Brown",
    "paym": [
      {
        "paymentAmnt": 4,
        "paymentDesc": "Cash Payment :"
      }
    ],
    "subTotal": 2.4,
    "time": "00:35:32",
    "total": 2.4
  },
  "-LwANPC0UYCmTnqm7DRV": {
    "date": "15\/12\/2019",
    "discount": 1,
    "due": 0,
    "items": [
      {
        "pamount": 2.4,
        "pname": "Granola",
        "pprice": 2.4,
        "punit": 1
      },
      {
        "pamount": 2.6,
        "pname": "Brownie",
        "pprice": 2.6,
        "punit": 1
      },
      {
        "pamount": 2.4,
        "pname": "Granola",
        "pprice": 2.4,
        "punit": 1
      },
      {
        "pamount": 2.6,
        "pname": "Brownie",
        "pprice": 2.6,
        "punit": 1
      }
    ],
    "name": "James Brown",
    "paym": [
      {
        "paymentAmnt": 5,
        "paymentDesc": "Cash Payment :"
      },
      {
        "paymentAmnt": 4,
        "paymentDesc": "Card Payment :"
      }
    ],
    "subTotal": 10,
    "time": "21:05:43",
    "total": 9
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me please, where I am doing wrong ?

Thanks.

Edit part
....
Product class

```
data class Product(var pName: String = "", var pUnit: Int = 1, var pPrice: Double = 00.00, var pAmount: Double = 00.00) : Parcelable {
constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
    parcel.readString(),
    parcel.readInt(),
    parcel.readDouble(),
    parcel.readDouble()
)

override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
    parcel.writeString(pName)
    parcel.writeInt(pUnit)
    parcel.writeDouble(pPrice)
    parcel.writeDouble(pAmount)
}

override fun describeContents(): Int {
    return 0
}

companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<Product> {
    override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Product {
        return Product(parcel)
    }

    override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Product?> {
        return arrayOfNulls(size)
    }
}
```

Also, the part tried here.

```
        val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
    val ref = rootRef.child("Sales").child("-LwIWKf-CTNTdwi4iMLU")
    val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            val product = dataSnapshot.getValue(Product::class.java)
            //println("pname : "+product?.pName)
            Log.d(TAG, product!!.pName)
        }

        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
           // Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()) //Don't ignore errors!
        }
    }
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
```

Also, tried Peter's solution it works, but I need to get "items" as an ArrayList
Thanks

Comment: About which list are you talking about? As I can see, you only need one product, right?

Comment: here this; `val generic: GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<Product>> =  object : GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<Product>>() {}
                            val items = h.child("items").getValue(generic)
                            items?.let { productList.addAll(it) }`

Comment: I don't understand. You try to get a single product or a list of products?

Comment: list of products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What actually need it to give me only the entries from a specific unique key

To get the entries from a specific unique key, for instance `-Lw37uyfuBA0AfTalp`, please use the following lines of code:

```
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val ref = rootRef.child("Sales").child("-Lw37uyfuBA0AfTalp")
val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        val product = dataSnapshot.getValue(Product::class.java)
        Log.d(TAG, product!!.time)
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()) //Don't ignore errors!
    }
}
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
```

The output in your logcat will be:

```
11:16:42
```

I just added a log statement to see that it works.

**Edit:**

According to your comment, if you want to get a list of products, please use the following lines of code:

```
val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val salesRef = rootRef.child("Sales")
val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        val productList = arrayListOf<Product>()
        for (ds in dataSnapshot.children) {
            val product = ds.getValue(Product::class.java)
            productList.add(product)
            Log.d(TAG, product!!.time)
        }
        //Do what you need to do with your list
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()) //Don't ignore errors!
    }
}
salesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
```

Comment: Hi @Alex, this doesn't give me any data. I think it is because the rest of the code I have.  `if (h.hasChild("items")) {
                            val generic: GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<Product>> =  object : GenericTypeIndicator<ArrayList<Product>>() {}
                            val items = h.child("items").getValue(generic)
                            items?.let { productList.addAll(it) }
                        }`    by using this code, I get all product entries as ArrayList, and using it later to display in recyclerview. Because in some case, it is multiple products listed.

Comment: But if you change this line `val product = dataSnapshot.getValue(Product::class.java)` with `val time = dataSnapshot.child("time").getValue(String::class.java)` and log `Log.d(TAG, time)`, do you get any output?

Comment: Not yet. in your code, `log.d` doesnt show anything. it is probably not getting `val product`. If I type there something else, message prints in the log. I will edit in the question this part and also, will add my `product` class.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Mamo, It didn't work like that, But after I edited it worked. It such a great help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should do the following:

```
ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Sales").child("-Lw37uyfuBA0AfTalp")

 ref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

        }

        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {

                    println("onDataChange")
                    if (p0.exists()) {
                         val date = p0.child("date").getValue(String::class.java)
                         val discount = p0.child("discount").getValue(String::class.java)
                        }
                }
    })
```

This will get you the data under the unique key

Comment: @DavidGreen did you try the answer?

Comment: Thanks @PeterHaddad. It helped a lot.